# Create Classroom annoucement with Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

Does exist a way to creare an Announcement in Google Classroom within Google App Script?
I've looked in [the reference](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/) but only the REST way is documented. 
In the editor it seems to exists a `Classroom.newAnnouncement`, but there's no documentation on what fields it requires and how to attach the created announcement to a course.

Any experience with that?

Comment: All Google Apps Script Advanced Services are "wrappers" for (and are analogous to) their corresponding REST APIs. Thus the documentation for the [Classroom REST API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements) is what you'll have to use. This [guide to Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) should help bring you up to speed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code.

```
 function createAnnounce() {
 var ClassSource =  {
 text: "STRINGS"+"\n"+"STRINGS"
 };

 Classroom.Courses.Announcements.create(ClassSource, COURSEID)
 Logger.log(ClassSource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is right on the money.
you can also add a file to the announcement as is present in the updated code bellow:

```
function Announcement() {
  var ClassSource =  {
 text: "STRINGS"+"\n"+"STRINGS",
     materials: [
      {
        driveFile:{
        driveFile: {
          id: "FileID", 
          title: "Sample Document"   
        },
        }   
      }
      ],
 };    
Classroom.Courses.Announcements.create(ClassSource, COURSEID)
 Logger.log(ClassSource);
}
```